# Is the sum of a subspace with itself that same subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Quick question. Let $U$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. I was asked to

> Express $U + U$ in terms of $U$.

My thought process is that, by definition, any linear combination $c\alpha + \beta$ of vectors $\alpha, \beta \in U$ belongs to $U$. In other words, every linear combination *within* $U$ maps to vectors *within* $U$. It seems to follow that

$$U + U = U$$

since $U + U$ is simply every possible linear combination of vectors within $U$. Is this correct?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: Strictly speaking you proved that $U+U \subseteq U$, but the other containment is even more trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically correct. To make it more formal, we can show $U + U = U$ by showing that both sides of the equation are subsets of the other.

First, it's fairly trivial to see that $U \subseteq U + U$ but just in case notice that if $u \in U$ is an arbitrary vector from $U$ then $u = u + 0 \in U + U$ and hence $U \subseteq U + U$.

Then, as you've noted, if $u, v \in U$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$ (the underlying field) then $\alpha u + \beta v$ represents an arbitrary vector from $U + U$, but because $U$ is a subspace of $V$ it's clear that $\alpha u + \beta v \in U$, and hence $U + U \subseteq U$.

Then since $U \subseteq U + U$ and $U + U \subseteq U$, we have $U = U + U$.

Comment: Even more simply, I think you can just say that subspaces are vector spaces by definition, and vector spaces are closed under addition and multiplication by definition (vector space axioms), so, since all vectors in $U+U$ are sums of vectors in $U$, they must be in $U$ by closure. Also, as you correctly mentioned, $0\in U$ by definition of vector space, so $u = u+0 \in U+U$. In general, the distinction between "subspace" and "vector space" is negligible, and this question is a perfect example of that ($V$ is an unnecessary detail here).

Comment: That's certainly fair. It depends a little on what has and hasn't been proven so far in the particular course but closure under addition and scalar multiplication is covered pretty early.